# validate url in php

Tags: php, validation

I have the following seems simple code in php; but the ptoblem is that it shows all valid links as "not valid"; any help appreciated:

```
<?php
   $m = "urllist.txt";
   $n = fopen($m, "r");
   while (!feof($n)) {
      $l = fgets($n);
      if (filter_var($l, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) === FALSE) {
          echo "NOT VALID - $l<br>";
      } else {
          echo "VALID - $l<br>";
      }
   }
   fclose($n);
?>
```

Comment: How are the URLs saved in the file? If you have more than one URL in one line or some characters at the end of the line that should show you that now a new URL is,  they will be always NOT VALID

Comment: I checked them in the same code one by one and they are valid; I checked the file and cleaned it; I went through this check, nothing seems wrong with the text file.

Comment: just echo the variable $l. then you can understand the type of url

Comment: it is already echo'ed; please check the code...

Comment: I tested the code right now. It works (half) if you use a URL like the URL of this site (this post) it say NOT VALID, but the second URL (google.com) is VALID

Comment: It has something to do with how filter_var works in this case

Comment: by the way. http://stackoverflow.com/  is NOT VALIDE, too with the filter_var, maybe RegEx is a better option to validate the URL

Comment: I tested other sites, and they show "NOT VALID" too...

Comment: If http:// stackoverflow.com/  is Not Valid, than you can not say the code is perfectly fine. The Code does what it should, but filter_var has some problems with URLs like http:// stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string returned by `fgets()` contains a trailing newline character that needs to be trimmed before you can validate it. Try out following code, I hope this will help you:

```
<?php
  $m = "urllist.txt";
  $n = fopen($m, "r");
  while (!feof($n)) {
    $l = fgets($n);
    if(filter_var(trim($l), FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
      echo "VALID - $l<br>";
    } else {
      echo "NOT VALID - $l<br>";
    }      
  }
  fclose($n);
?>
```

I have tried with following urls:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/
https://www.google.co.in/
https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=bf4HVLOmF8XFoAOg_4HoCg&gws_rd=ssl
www.google.com
http://www.example.com
example.php?name=Peter&age=37
```

and get following result:

```
VALID - http://stackoverflow.com/ 
VALID - https://www.google.co.in/ 
VALID - https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=bf4HVLOmF8XFoAOg_4HoCg&gws_rd=ssl 
NOT VALID - www.google.com 
VALID - http://www.example.com 
NOT VALID - example.php?name=Peter&age=37
```

Comment: trim() is needed because while reading lines from text file, one space is appended at the end of each line.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you have some symbols at end of each line '\n'

I think you can just use trim function before validate the $l like this:

```
filter_var(trim($l), FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) === TRUE
```

maybe this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. It must be helpful. I have tested it and its working.

```
<?php
    $m = "urllist.txt";
    $n = fopen($m, "r");
    while (!feof($n)) {
        $l = fgets($n);
        if(filter_var(trim($l), FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
            echo "URL is not valid";
        }
        else{
            echo "URL is valid";
        }
    }
    fclose($n);
?>
```

Here is the [**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/mddTAIDM)

Comment: It gave same results; my code gave the following results:

NOT VALID - http//www.google.com 
NOT VALID - http//www.bing.com 
NOT VALID - http//www.yahoo.com 
NOT VALID - http://www.michaelking.ca/ 
NOT VALID - http://michaelking.ca/ 
NOT VALID - http://www.mekdam.com/ 
NOT VALID - http://mekdam.com/ 
VALID - http://oilpainting.mkzg.com/

Your code gave: 
URL is not validURL is not validURL is not validURL is not validURL is not validURL is not validURL is not validURL is valid

Comment: did you check the demo?

Comment: The demo is not the same code. The problem was with `fgets()`.

Comment: Yeah that's right. I couldn't include the file in demo.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the different filters available to see where it fails:

- FILTER_FLAG_SCHEME_REQUIRED - Requires URL to be an RFC compliant URL
  (like http:// example)
- FILTER_FLAG_HOST_REQUIRED - Requires URL to
  include host name (like http:// www.example.com)
- FILTER_FLAG_PATH_REQUIRED - Requires URL to have a path after the
  domain name (like www. example.com/example1/test2/)
- FILTER_FLAG_QUERY_REQUIRED - Requires URL to have a query string
  (like "example.php?name=Peter&age=37")

(cc of http://www.w3schools.com/php/filter_validate_url.asp)

You can try the good old regex too:

```
if (!preg_match("/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i",$url))
```